# Haverá um Careers para o StackOverflow em Português?

Tags: novo-recurso, careers

Estive dando uma olhada no Careers 2.0 do StackOverflow e senti falta de oportunidades no Brasil, se encontrar 5 oportunidades já é demais.

Fiquei com a dúvida, será criado um Careers para o StackOverflow em Português?

**EDIÇÃO 1**

Acredito que com um Careers específico em português, o trabalho de divulgação do Careers ficaria muito mais fácil, pois muitas vezes empresas não divulgam no Careers 2.0 devido a falta de conhecimento dessa possibilidade.

Comment: Interessante a proposta. Mas acharia mais viável dar a sugestão de internacionalizar o Careers original e possibilitar o filtro por região. Mas creio que esse não é o maior dos problemas. O duro é convencer as empresas a usarem.

Comment: @utluiz já há a possibilidade de filtrar por Brasil, Santa Catarina, etc... O problema é que não há oportunidades brasileiras lá mesmo, acredito que com um Careers específico em português traria mais vagas.

Comment: Depois que o SOPT graduar e for mais conhecido pelos brasileiros, acredito que isso dependeria do grupo StackExchange fazer algum investimento por aqui, talvez em forma de divulgação e parcerias.

Comment: @utluiz Concordo que é um grande problema convencer as empresas a aderirem, mas maior ainda é a falta conhecimento das próprias empresas em poderem divulgar no StackOverflow suas vagas. Ta faltando muita divulgação.

Comment: Concordo, Lucas. Espero que isso ocorra num futuro próximo.

Comment: É, se a empresas não conseguem nem montar um anúncio que realmente pede as qualificações que ela precisa, não consegue escrever os nomes das tecnologias adotadas, e esta é a parte mais fácil de todo o processo de seleção (e estou falando até nos líderes especializados em recrutamento para TI), imagine como é difícil elas adotarem uma ferramenta nova. Por outro lado, já vi várias vezes sites e aplicativos  que não ajudavam nada mais do que outras soluções já existentes terem muito sucesso por serem diferentes. Tudo pode acontecer.

Comment: Mas o problema real é não ter usuários suficientes no SOpt. Se tivermos uma boa parte dos profissionais de programação aqui e quem sabe de outras áreas de TI em um outro site em português, as empresas não poderiam ignorar o o Careers. Mas não bastaria usuários que vieram uma vezes e foram embora, que fizeram um pergunta para resolver um problema pontual e nunca mais voltou. Tem que ter usuários ativos, não precisaria ser altamente ativos, mas pelo menos que frequentem o site eventualmente. Os que aparecem e somem não acrescentam nada duradouro ao site.

Comment: De uma certa forma isto já foi perguntando antes mas não conseguimos uma resposta oficial. Tivemos algo extra oficial de que não estava nos planos. A pergunta como um todo ainda deixa dúvidas como nosso site será graduado principalmente porque sempre foi dito que o nosso site é diferente.

Comment: @bigown Não concordo em fazer perguntas no SOpt, se consigo escrever em inglês acho bem mais vantajoso perguntar no SO global, onde minha dúvida poderá ser lida/aproveitada por desenvolvedores de qualquer parte do mundo, visto que inglês é uma linguagem global. É por isso que não participo ativamente perguntando e respondendo por aqui, se eu perguntar em português minha dúvida e a resposta só poderão ser utilizadas por brasileiros.

Comment: @bigown Entendi.. Lamentável isto, mas pelo menos podiam fazer um trabalho de publicidade no Brasil referente a esta possibilidade. :/

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob então o Careers ideal para você é o global mesmo, lá seu currículo poderia ser visto globalmente. O Careers em português só poderia ser visto por quem lê português. Um SOpt ou um Careers PT é útil para quem não precisa, não quer ou não pode usar uma versão global. Inglês  é falado nativamente por cerca de 5% da população. A imensa maioria das outras pessoas não entendem o inglês e os que entendem, isso não é suficiente para ter conversas complexas frutíferas. De qualquer forma sem um SOpt forte não haverá um Careers PT.

Comment: O anúncio de vagas no carrers é pago?

Comment: @bigown vendo por este lado, realmente só existirá um Careers Pt quando a comunidade Pt crescer bem mais.

Comment: @perdeu Acredito que sim. Nunca li mais a fundo em como fazer um anúncio no Careers.

Comment: Olha que aqui em Portugal era capaz de dar certo, visto que não temos nada oficial para isso. Uma boa ideia para aqui mesmo. Aqui funciona mais na base do "tenho um amigo interessado".

Comment: O Careers faz o que é certo, cobra das empresas e não dos profissionais interessados em vagas. O que torna mais difícil fazer dar certo, pelo menos no Brasil. Algumas empresas teriam que sair da zona de conforto de acessar currículos gratuitamente e pagar por isso.Na prática as melhores empresas pagam fortunas para empresas recrutadoras conseguirem profissionais para elas. Para as melhores, o Careers seriam uma redução de custo. Para algumas empresas ver a atividade do profissional no SOpt seria uma forma de avaliação também. Nem sempre ela poderá avaliar a atividade no SO.

Comment: E vou dizer uma coisa: aqui tem muitas respostas melhores do que encontra no SO e só foi possível porque as pessoas que responderam não se sentiam confortáveis com o inglês e agora podem responder.

Comment: @bigown Acredito que deveria ser feito um 'merge' entre os dois de perguntas mais votadas, de tempo em tempo, para que o conhecimento não se privasse a uma unica lingua que é menos falada.

Comment: Mas esse é um problema da humanidade, as pessoas falam línguas diferentes, possuem culturas diferentes. Você está buscando um idealismo impossível. O Sopt deu uma solução concreta para o problema. Todo mundo já pensou em como fazer algo do tipo funcionar mas não há maneira realmente viável. E se seu argumento for válido, então todos os outros sites sobre programação do mundo deveriam ser fechados e só existir o SO. Você pode torcer pelo seu site preferido, mas ele não é solução para todos os problemas do mundo.

Comment: @bigown Concordo plenamente com você, eu mesmo por muitas vezes tive que pedir ajuda ao redigir uma pergunta ou resposta em inglês, mas acho muito interessante que de fato em inglês afetará um número muito maior de pessoas do que em português, ainda sou da opinião de que alguma forma de tradução das melhores questões para o inglês seria algo bem interessante.